# Proving a Probability Proof in Matrix Form

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

I came across the following mathematical theorem:

\begin{aligned}
&\text{if } Y \sim N(0, I_N) \text{ and } A \text{ is an orthogonal projection, then} \\
&Y^T A Y \sim \chi^2(k) \text{ with } k = \text{rank}(A) .
\end{aligned}

Where:

- $\sim N$ is a Normal Distribution
- $\sim \chi^2(k)$ is a Chi-Square Distribution

**I am trying to learn how to prove this**

My "noob" way of proving this would be to rely on the fact that a Normal Distribution squared is a Chi-Square Distribution. Therefore, in matrix algebra, the same principle should hold. That is:

- $Y$ squared in matrix algebra becomes $Y^T Y$
- If $Y \sim N(0, I_N)$ then $Y^T Y$ is $\sim \chi^2(k)$
- And due to the algebraic properties of the $A$ matrix, $Y^T  A  Y$ can be thought of as just $Y^T Y$

Therefore, the above relationship is likely true.

**Can someone please show me how to prove this?**

Thanks!

Comment: If $Y$ is joint *standard* normal, so is $Z=QY$ for any constant orthogonal matrix $Q$ (proof: make a change of variable in the PDF of $Y$). When $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix that diagonalises $A$, then $Y^TAY=Z^T\pmatrix{I_k\\ &0}Z=Z_1^2+\cdots+Z_k^2\sim\chi^2(k)$.